# Failed Installation of DeployR Open 8.0.0 on Windows 7 64 bits

Tags: r, mongodb, deployr, microsoft-r, rro

I  try to install DeployR open 8.0.0 on Windows 7. With all dependencies installed as instructed in https://deployr.revolutionanalytics.com/documents/admin/install/#install-win I still continue got an error like the following screenshot. I've installed JRE 7u72, Revolution R open 8.0.0, MongoDB in %TEMP%/MONGODB_DEPLOYR/mongodb-win32-x86_64-2008plus-2.6.7 and deployrRserve_7.4.2 library. What else can be wrong?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HwiHF.png)

Comment: Have you got any solution for this? I am also facing the same problem.